# Can't DELETE when POST, PUT, and GET works, AngularJS-CORS, Flask-CORS

Tags: python, angularjs, flask, cors

I'm at a loss, i cant understand on how come DELETE requests are not coming through when POST, PUT and GET works just fine. And I'm pretty sure that I already did every bit configuration necessary for CORS to work. I'm using AngularJS and Flask-CORS extension

And here's my current work:

Angular Config:

```
angular.module('...' [...]).config(function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
  delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
});
```

Angular factory:

```
angular.module('...').factory('...'), function($http) {
  return {
    deleteElectronicAddress: function (partyId, contactMechanismId) {
      return $http({
        url: urlBase + 'party/' + partyId + '/contact-mechanism/' + contactMechanismId,
        method: 'DELETE',
      });
    },

    someMoreMethods: { ... }
  }
}
```

My Flask codes, (I'm using the proposed app structure by Miguel Grinberg on his book Flask Web Development)

config.py

```
class Config:
    ...

    CORS_HEADERS = 'Content-Type'
    CORS_RESOURCES = {r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}}
    CORS_METHODS = ['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'PUT', 'OPTIONS', 'HEAD']

    ...
```

project_folder/app/__init__.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask.ext.cors import CORS
from config import config

db = SQLAlchemy()


def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    config[config_name].init_app(app)

    db.init_app(app)
    CORS(app)

    from .api_1_0 import api as api_1_0_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(api_1_0_blueprint, url_prefix='/api/v1.0')

    return app
```

I'm currently using Flask-CORS v1.7.4.

project_folder/app/api/party_contact_mechanisms.py:

```
from datetime import date
from flask import jsonify
from .. import db
from ..models import PartyContactMechanism
from . import api

@api.route(
'/party/<int:party_id>' +
'/contact-mechanism/<int:contact_mechanism>', methods=['DELETE'])
def unlink_party_contact_mechanism(party_id, contact_mechanism):
"""Unlink the contact mechanism onto the party."""
     party_contact = PartyContactMechanism.query \
        .filter_by(party_id=party_id) \
        .filter_by(contact_mechanism_id=contact_mechanism) \
        .first()

     party_contact.thru_date = str(date.today())

     db.session.commit()

     return jsonify(success=True)
```

I already tested this with httpie, both on my local machine and on another machine connected on the LAN, and it works just fine.

I'm running both angular and flask with 0.0.0.0 host configuration so that it can be accessible on the other machines connected on network.

here are my request and response headers when invoke from browser

REQUEST HEADERS:

```
OPTIONS /api/v1.0/party/32232/contact-mechanism/80667 HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.61.18.217:5000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101      Firefox/31.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: http://0.0.0.0:9000
Access-Control-Request-Method: DELETE
Connection: keep-alive
```

RESPONSE HEADERS:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Allow: POST, OPTIONS, DELETE
access-control-allow-origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Content-Length: 0
Server: Werkzeug/0.9.6 Python/2.7.6
Date: Mon, 18 Aug 2014 07:20:18 GMT
```

here are the request and response headers when invoke from httpie:

REQUEST HEADERS:

```
DELETE /api/v1.0/party/32232/contact-mechanism/80667 HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress
Content-Length: 0
Host: 10.61.18.217:5000
User-Agent: HTTPie/0.8.0
```

RESPONSE HEADERS:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, POST, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 21
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Mon, 18 Aug 2014 07:31:05 GMT
Server: Werkzeug/0.9.6 Python/2.7.6

{
   "success": true
}
```

Comment: the problem is in the response that is returned to the browser

`Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST`

only post is allowed there.

In httpie, the response is different 

`Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, POST, PUT`

DELETE is allowed there.

Comment: @idursun yeah, I noticed that too, but how come that happens when I clearly set Access-Control-Allow-Methods to DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, POST, PUT DELETE via the config file CORS_METHODS = ['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'PUT', 'OPTIONS', 'HEAD']. And i clearly added the DELETE on the route. So how come those doesn’t manifest on my response headers.

Comment: Maybe a flask-cors issue ? Look here: https://github.com/wcdolphin/flask-cors/blob/master/flask_cors.py


l.29 ALL_METHODS not contains DELETE.


l.269:271 use ALL_METHODS on OPTIONS request

Comment: So it means the problem is on Flask side. I have never worked with Flask but I would probably simplify the configuration and try to figure out why it is not responding as it should. For example try: `app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = "Content-Type"
app.config['CORS_RESOURCES'] = {r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}}` instead of class based config.

Comment: @idursun I did check on my app.config via shell and its all there, but that one you mentioned being a flask-cors issue, seems fishy, i'll try to post and issue there, maybe it really is. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got what i was doing wrong now,

actually there's another route on my `project_folder/app/api/party_contact_mechanisms.py` file which i didn’t bother adding on my sample, since i thought its irrelevant (well i though wrong)

here it is:

```
@api.route(
'/party/<int:party_id>' +
'/contact-mechanism/<int:contact_mechanism>',
methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin(methods=['POST'])
def link_party_contact_mechanism(party_id, contact_mechanism):
"""Link the contact mechanism onto the party."""
    party_contact = PartyContactMechanism(
        party_id=party_id, contact_mechanism=contact_mechanism,
        from_date=str(date.today()), thru_date=None
    )

    db.session.add(party_contact)
    db.session.commit()

    return jsonify({})
```

as you can see it has the the same route rule but with different method, in here its POST.

And before I used Flask-CORS v1.7 i was using v1.3, that explains the `@cross_origin` decorator, since that's the only way to make your route CORS enabled (or if you want it on all your routes, you put it on your `before_request`)

The thing i missed with the new version is, yes you can now make your whole app CORS enabled by initializing it, just like i did on my `project_folder/app/__init__.py`, and yes you can still do specific routes via the `@cross_origin', but when you do, it overwrites the global config, and in my case I have two routes with the same rule but different methods and only one having the @cross_origin decorator and that's that root of the problem.

I just deleted it and it works just fine now. Be warned adding another `@cross_origin` decorator on your other route wont fix it, it seems it only reads the first occurrence of it.